# Heroku automatically changing RAILS_ENV and RACK_ENV variables to "production" on every deploy

Tags: heroku

Every time I push a new version to my staging heroku app, the RACK_ENV and RAILS_ENV variables are changed to "production", instead of "staging" which is the value I manually assigned. This started happening a couple of hours ago.
A line like this is logged on the activity page on the heroku site on every deploy:
 v741 app_owner@gmail.com: Add RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, PATH, LANG, GEM_PATH config 6 minutes ago

I should talk to heroku support, but it seems that now the only place where questions can be asked is here, they remove the site support...

Comment: They have support here https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new. After you search in the Help section, the "open a support ticket" option is located at the bottom. I just submitted a ticket regarding this for my app

Comment: Thanks! the open a new ticket link is pretty hidden, is good to force people to search first, but...

Answer (score 6):

Same here. Fortunately, it does not happen after a rollback.

Fortunately a deploy on production does not set the variables to staging !

EDIT:

Heroku answer on a ticket: Hi, looks like a bug on our end. I'm notifying our ruby team

EDIT 2:

They said the bug was fixed yesterday, and yes, it was. But… the bug has just happened again right now……

Comment: Hey Heroku - any status on this? This bug just broke my app.

Comment: No status… They answer on a ticket we posted and solved the bug yesterday, but it has just happened to me right now…