# Heroku / Rake overwriting RAILS_ENV

Tags: deployment, heroku, rake, staging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Heroku automatically changing RAILS_ENV and RACK_ENV variables to “production” on every deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702140/heroku-automatically-changing-rails-env-and-rack-env-variables-to-production-o)

I am currently trying to write a Rake script that will run the commands I need to do a deployment to my staging app, that will use asset_sync to copy over my assets to my cdn.

```
namespace :deploy do
 desc 'Deploy the app'
 task :staging do
  app = "app-name"
  remote = "git@heroku.com:#{app}.git"

  system "git push #{remote} master"
  system "heroku run rake assets:precompile --app #{app}"
end
```

end

However when I run this Heroku is overwriting my RAILS_ENV (amongst others) back to production.

Running Heroku releases afterwards

```
v143  Deploy 2b3aa3f                              10m ago
v142  Add RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, PATH, LANG, G..    10m ago
```

Any ideas why it might be doing this?

Many thanks

Phil

Answer (score 1):

Another user is [experiencing the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702140/heroku-automatically-changing-rails-env-and-rack-env-variables-to-production-o). Given you configured the variables, maybe an Heroku bug.

Try to open a ticket at Heroku.

If you haven't [configured the variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) yet, make sure to change [Ruby environment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support) `RAILS_ENV` and `RACK_ENV` to `staging`.

```
$ heroku config:add RAILS_ENV=staging
$ heroku config:add RACK_ENV=staging
```

Comment: Thanks!! - suppose it was bad timing to write a rake task at the same time Heroku developed a related bug.